# Receive and Display MQTT Stream at Pentaho Dashboard

Tags: mqtt, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to disdplay (and process) incoming MQTT-messages in a Pentaho dashboard, using their CCC-Charts.

I tried setting up a kettle transformation, which I then uploaded to my Pentaho server an use it as a datasource.(I tested running the transformation within spoon and it worked, so the issue shold be somewhere else). When I try to display the dashboard, it tells me 'Error processing component(component name)' while the server throws this exception:

```
Caused by: org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceCreationException: Unable to parse the document: ResourceKey{schema=pt.webdetails.cda.settings.CdaRepositoryResourceLoader:, identifier=/home/admin/MqttReceive2.ktr, factoryParameters={}, parent=null}
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a proper way to do this?

cheers

Edit:
I found solutions working arround this problem using a websocket implementation, but this isn´t quite what I need.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to include solutions. If you have a solution please add it as a proper answer (including enough detail to be useful to others) and then it can be voted on and marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to solve this, is to make use of a data service.

Here is what I came up with:

You can use Kettle to receive MQTT-Data and process it within your transformation:
[image: kettle transformation]

You can attach a data service to any step, by right clicking->Data Services->New
The service name needs to be unique among all data services and the data service type needs to be set to streaming:

[image: dataServiceSetup]

The whole transformation needs to be saved to a Pentaho repository(basically the internal filesystem of Pentaho)

With this you can create a dashboard by following these instructions:

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/CTools/Create_Streaming_Service_Dashboard

To break it down for you:

1. In the datasource Panel, you need to select 'streaming over data service' and enter a streaming data service name, as well as the query.
2. The parameters need to be set to:

   - Window Mode: Row Based
   - Window Size: 50 (If you want to work with 50 datapoints in your dashboard)
   - Window Every: 1 (This determines the frequency, in which your graph will be updated)
   - Window Limit: 0
3. In the component panel, you need to select the component of your choice and use the datasource you just created as 'Datasource'.
   The parameters need to be set as follows:

   - Don't Block the UI While Executing: True
   - Clears Before Pre Execution: False
4. Create a fronted layout and bind the component to a layout HTML object.

Answer (score 1):

I found solutions working arround this problem using a websocket implementation, but this isn´t quite what I need.

For those who are interested:

https://github.com/thomaslaurenson/MQTT-Subscription-Examples

basically it uses java script to subscribe to a MQTT broker and receive data, which you can then use within your Dashboard. The whole code can simply be injected into your board setup and is ready to be used.

It's quite self explanatory and easy to use.

Comment: This is basically a link only answer, when the link breaks the answer becomes useless. Please update the answer with at least the basic details of what is pointed to by the link.